app/Config/Database.php file is not writable
Trying to setup a free hrms tool(PHPHR version 13), everything works fine till I try to connect it with the datbase. it throws 'app/Config/Database.php file is not writable!'
The database.php file is encrypted and is not generating any logs as well.
I have tried changing the owner of file and do chmod 777 still the same error.
I am not familar with PHP and also the code is encrypted with ioncube loader so cannot figure out what is the issue.
I am using
PHP v-8.2,
apache2 latest,
ioncube loader latest,
mysql - latest;
